# Is it possible to get physical path of uploaded file using js/jquery?

Tags: filepath

I am trying for getting uploaded files actual physical path using JS or Jquery.
Currently I tried var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(file);
Its proving temp path like 
blob:http://fiddle.jshell.net/b298c63f-9501-4b09-b62e-c5eb01d4aaf3

Comment: It's insecure, and you cannot do it in modern browsers. But you can do it in IE8.